# marginal cdf question

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a collection of $n$ independent random variables, where $F_{X_i}(x)$ denotes the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $X_i$.

(a)  Find the CDF of the random variable $Y= \max \{X_1,...,X_n\}$ in terms of the marginal CDFs $F_{X_1}(x),...,F_{X_n}(x)$.

(b)  Find the CDF of the random variable $Z= \min\{X_1,...,X_n\}$in terms of the marginal CDFs $F_{X_1}(x),...,F_{X_n}(x)$.

A little lost on how to start the question? Any input would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

You asked now new question but did not accept yet previously given answers to old questions. I decide for myself whether it makes sense to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (a), the random variable $Y$ is defined as $max\{X_{1},X_{2},\cdots,X_{n}\}$. Consider the event $\{Y < y\}$. When expressed this event in terms of $X$'s, it becomes $\{max\{X_{1},X_{2},\cdots,X_{n}\} < y\}$. As the maximum $X$ itself is less than $y$, then the rest of the $X$'s
 are also less than $y$ and hence, the event becomes $\{max\{X_{1},X_{2},\cdots,X_{n}\} < y\}=\{X_{1}<y,X_{2}<y,\cdots,X_{n}<y\}$. So,
 \begin{eqnarray*}
 P\{Y<y\}&=&P\{max\{X_{1},X_{2},\cdots,X_{n}\} < y\}\\
 &=&P\{X_{1}<y,X_{2}<y,\cdots,X_{n}<y\}\\
 &=&P\{X_{1}<y\}\;\; P\{X_{2}<y\}\cdots P\{X_{n}<y\}\qquad \mbox{by ind. of X's}\\
 &=&\Pi_{k=1}^{n}P\{X_{k}<y\}
 \end{eqnarray*}
Now, think of an appropriate event to be considered on $Z$ to obtain its distribution.

Answer (score 0):

$$Pr(Y \leq y) = Pr(X_1 \leq y, \ldots, X_n \leq y) = \prod_{i=1}^n Pr(X_i \leq y)$$

$$Pr(Z \leq z) = 1 - Pr(Z> z) =1-Pr(X_1 > z, \ldots, X_n > z) = 1-\prod_{i=1}^n Pr(X_i >z )$$